# Why doesn't the textbox resize to the entire div in IE? Chrome is fine

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

A IE Resizing problem!? The code is pretty simple: I've got a div and I want a text-box that's 100% of the DIV. It must show the red line of the div (if I use height:100%, width:100% it eats away my border :-( ).

Html:

```
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div{

    width:500px;
    height:500px; 
    border:solid 1px red;
    padding:1px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
}

textarea{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

I hope you guys have a clue. The DTD in the example is HTML Strict. Code example: http://jsfiddle.net/QJYuz/

**I'm trying to find the reason why as well.** Please specify any links to blogs / specifications **why** this problem occurs.

Comment: Experimentally, I've found that I have more success if objects are at least one pixel smaller than their containers.  So, you could try having a width of 99% or 499px, for example.  I'm not promising it will work for you, but I have used that to fix IE rendering issues in the past.

Comment: @Andrew, me too... but with big resolutions it will not work :-) so I'm trying to understand the reason behind this madness.

Comment: Reason?  This is IE, expect to find little reason here. :)  It's how IE8 renders certain form controls - poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support setting both `left` and `right` (nor `top` and `bottom`) at the same time. Instead try setting `width` and `height` to `100%` (but you'll need to remove padding and border in that case):

```
textarea{
   position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
textarea {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

instead. While some browsers do honor setting the top/bottom/left/right all at the same time, it's not standard.

Comment: You'd still need to set borders and whatnot. but the height/width should solve your "fill" problems. The absolution positioning shouldn't be necessary unless you've got other content within that div that could push the textarea around.

Answer (score 0):

One method that looks good in both:  http://jsfiddle.net/QJYuz/6/

My change to textarea:

```
textarea{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 99%;
    height: 98%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I just set the `width` and `height` to 99% and 98%.  It looks good in both and saves the border.  I also put in the `overflow: auto` to get rid if IE8's ugly grayed-out scrollbar, until you actually *need* a scrollbar.